# Сетевые точки безопасности

Tags: безопасность

На экзамене попался теоретический вопрос "Сетевые точки безопасности". Не совсем понимаю, что именно подразумевается под этим словосочетанием. Про что именно писать?
Заранее спасибо^-^

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в конспекте или спросить у составителя вопроса?

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю что этот термин придумал ваш преподаватель. Сам преподаю ИБ как специальность, но такого термина не слышал :)

Но могу предположить пару вариантов:

1. Возможно это точки обмена с внешней средой, так же называемые внешним сетевым периметром безопасности, на пример такой точкой в вашей сети может быть маршрутизатор (или группы маршрутизаторов) через который осуществляется доступ к сети Интернет;
2. Так же ваш преподаватель этим термином мог называть конкретное инженерно-техническое средство осуществления корпоративной политики информационной безопасности, на пример какой-то сертифицированный государством или какой-то организацией маршрутизатор;
3. Ну и как вариант, композицию двух вышеперечисленных объектов сетеобразующих устройств, на пример такую как DMZ (демилитаризованную зону организованную несколькими маршрутизаторами/межсетевыми экранами);
4. И последнее, возможно самое простое решение - самое верное. Ваш преподаватель мог иметь под этим термином **любой** сетевой сервис доступный из внешней сети и *требующий* обеспечения информационной безопасности, а значит внимания со стороны специалистов ИБ.